# Devise issue, "update" method is now deleting my user account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, simple-form

I am having the weirdest issue with my app using Devise & Simple_Form. All my features were working fine and now when I go to "update" my account, it simply cancels the account. I didn't change anything in my controller or even my edit form. I found this issue creeped up after pushing to Heroku and noticed the change now in both development and production, so I'm unsure of what is causing the issue.

**Solution:** Within my full automatically generated devise form, there was a missing `</div>` that caused my update and cancel features to get mixed together. Because of the way devise formats the forms, it was unclear amongst all the code that this tag wasn't closed! Tricky catch.

Is there a way to override the devise default to fix this weird error?

```
 <%= form_for(resource, 
   as: resource_name, 
   url: registration_path(resource_name),  
   html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
 <%= devise_error_messages! %>

 <div>
   <%= f.label :profile_photo %><br />
   <%= f.file_field :profile_photo, label: "Image" %>
   <%= image_tag (current_owner.profile_photo.url(:thumb)) %>
 **</div>**

 <div>
   <%= f.submit "Update" %>
 </div>
 <% end %>

 <h3>Cancel my account</h3>

 <p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), 
  data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>
```

Comment: I had the same problem, this is difficult to debug. Thanks for posting the solution friend! =) You just should post the solution as a answer, and not as a question edit.

Comment: If it's a problem with the generator, you should report the issue to https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues

Comment: Thanks for the post. I was stuck on a problem for ages regarding why the devise "update" button was deleting the user - turns out it was my own buggy front-end code! I fixed it by tidying up the div tags and putting the form_for block in the right place. (At first I thought it was a database thing and luckily it wasn't! :)

Answer (score 4):

Put the "Cancel my Account" button outside of your form.

Comment: The "Cancel my account" button isn't actually in the "form_for" block, it's right outside the form at the end of the page. I don't know how the routing got switched up since it's all set automatically in Devise. Is there a way to explicitly set a method/route withing the `<%= f.submit "Update" %>` line so that it properly updates?

Answer (score 1):

Very tricky! I spent 1 hour trying to solve this and it was a missing `</div>`!
Thanks for asking and answering this question.